# 差分抽出について

Tags: emeditor

2つのファイルAとBがあります
**ファイルA**

```
1、1234、4567、890
2、2345、5678、891
3、3456、6789、891
```

**ファイルB**

```
1、1234、4567、890
3、3456、6789、891
```

この場合
ファイルAにある

```
2、2345、5678、891
```

だけを抜き出して他のファイルに書き込むことは出来るでしょうか。

ちなみにファイルは10,000行ほどあります。

Answer (score 0):

EmEditor でファイルA と B を開いて、B、A の順にアクティブにして （抽出差分の存在するファイルを最後にアクティブにして）、次のマクロを実行してください。すると、差分行だけを抽出して新規ファイルを作成します。

マクロを実行するには、まず、以下のマクロを `ExtractDiff.jsee` などのファイル名で保存します。そして、[マクロ] メニューから [選択] を選択して、保存したマクロを選択します。そして、上記のようにファイルA をアクティブにしてから[マクロ] メニューの [実行] を選択してください。

```
if( editor.Compare( 0, "", "", "" ) == eeDiff ) {
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4323);  // Clear all Bookmarks
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4593);  // Boookmark Changes
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4590);  // Extract Bookmarked Lines to New File
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4497);  // Reset Compare mode
}
```

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございました。実行できました。

もう一つお聞きしたいのですがAのファイルに余分な一行が加わっている場合、
たとえば、
1、1234、4567、890、１
2、2345、5678、891、２
3、3456、6789、891、３

でBのファイルがそのままの場合、最初の4列のみで比較して同じようなことを行う事は可能でしょうか。

申し訳ありません。もう少しアドバイスを頂けれたらと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Aのファイルに余分な１行、でなく、「１列」が加わっている場合でしょうか? できれば、新しい質問にしていただけると、サンプルが見やすくてわかりやすいかと思います。

Comment: Yutaka様
改めて質問させて頂きます。
引き続きよろしくお願いします。