# 列数の異なる2つのテキストデータを比較、差分のある行を抽出したい

Tags: emeditor

2つのファイルAとBがあります。

**ファイルA**

```
1,1234,4567,890,1
2,2345,5678,891,2
3,3456,6789,891,3
```

**ファイルB**

```
1,1234,4567,890
3,3456,6789,891
```

この場合、ファイルAにある

```
2,2345,5678,891,2
```

だけを抜き出して他のファイルに書き込むことは出来るでしょうか。
ちなみにファイルは10,000行ほどあります。

なお、ファイルAは5列、ファイルBは4列で、ファイルAの最後の列はファイルBには無く
差分の抽出はファイルAの最初の4列とファイルBの4列の比較によります。

以上よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [差分抽出について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69827/%e5%b7%ae%e5%88%86%e6%8a%bd%e5%87%ba%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

Comment: 質問のタイトルは (一覧からでも中身を把握できるよう) **具体的な表現** を心掛けてください。今回の質問は前回と違って「特定の列のみを比較したい」ですよね？ / 「〇〇について」という書き方はつい使いがちですが、何が知りたい・分からないのかが曖昧な表現だと思います。

Comment: `emeditor` タグがついてますが 他のプログラム言語で実装した方がいいと思うのですが。

Answer (score 0):

ファイルA から最後の列を削除してから比較、変更行の抽出を行います。マクロの場合、ファイルB、ファイルA の順でアクティブにしてから、以下のマクロを実行してください。マクロ実行後、ファイルA の最後の列は削除された状態になっているため、そのまま保存しないようにご注意ください。

```
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22528);  // switch to CSV mode
document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);
document.selection.EndOfLine(false,eeLineView);
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(3962);  // Delete Column
if( editor.Compare( 0, "", "", "" ) == eeDiff ) {
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4323);  // Clear all Bookmarks
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4593);  // Boookmark Changes
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4590);  // Extract Bookmarked Lines to New File
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4497);  // Reset Compare mode
}
```